# How to solve "The system cannot find the path specified " when starting Fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

While starting fluentd in windows as `"fluentd -c 'D:\opt\td-agent\etc\td-agent\td-agent.conf"`.

I am getting the error as:

> "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Tried removing the ' in the file path?

fluentd -c D:\opt\td-agent\etc\td-agent\td-agent.conf

Seems to be a problem with where you put fluentd, the workaround is to put it on default (suggested) folder in C not in D. See if that solves your problem!

https://github.com/treasure-data/omnibus-td-agent/issues/186

Otherwise manually changing the path in the bat file to resolve the issue